# Render a view and show a <p> using Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my app I have this small method:

```
$('#checkOut').click(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $.get("/Checkout/AdressAndPayment");
    });
```

What I want is simply to show the `#loading` paragraph:

```
<p id="loading" style="display: none" class="center">
    Loading. Please wait... @Html.Image("~/Images/Functional/ajax-loader.gif", null, new {@class = "nullify"})
</p>
```

So that my user knows that the app is computing something in background.

But I also need to render a whole new view in my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdressAndPayment()
{
    mOrder = new OrderInfo();

    ShoppingCart cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(HttpContext);

    mOrder = cart.CreateOrder(mOrder);

    return View(mOrder);
}
```

And this does not work. I mean, the whole process goes fine, and if I use a standard `ActionLink` or a button with `using (Html.BeginForm())`, it works fine, but I would like to do both: display the `<p>`, and then get the view. How could I do it?

Comment: need to do something with response in complete callback of `$.get`. You have no callback for it ... see [$.get() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Oh, ok, so I would need to send the data obtained to either a div or something bearing a class / id?

Comment: if that's all you are doing can make it even simpler using `load()`

Comment: Yeah, but it loads back the whole view, so all my partial views that are inclued in the layout are loaded twice, but my need is only to render the view once as if I'm simply calling the ActionResult

Comment: can extract only part of page also with load() also...see docs

Comment: I have a similar call made by another part of my JS that works: `$('form').submit(function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    });` Is there any way to achieve something similar? Still testing the solutions offered by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant of the solutions, but here's what I did:

First, the view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AdressAndPayment", "Checkout", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "checkOut" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout >>"/>
}
```

Then the javascript:

```
$('#checkOut').click(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
});
```

And everything works because I am submitting a form at the beginning. But to all those who put a comment: what could I do with the callback that would render the whole view, including partial views in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the .done callback

```
$.get("/Checkout/AdressAndPayment")
.done(function() {
   makeViewCallinSomeWay();
});
```

Are you using Yii?

Comment: Nope, well, I don't think so, I am using jQuery with my MVC.